# Jquery show loading div while waiting for script to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript that looks something like this

```
$("#loading").show();

// script that takes some time

$("#loading").hide();
```

I want to show the loading dialog then wait for the script to end and then close it. But it doesn't work like this. It opens the loading dialog after the script is finished and it stays open.

What's the problem?

Comment: _"script that takes some time"_ must be async... Invoke `.hide()` in the callback...

Comment: can you give me an example please?

Comment: Can you share _"// script that takes some time"_ ?

Comment: I use for cyclus that manipulates with some data from array

Answer (score 0):

Try to use toggle

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#loading").toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="loading">Loading</p>

<button>show hide loading</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function () {
     $("#loading").hide();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#loading").show();
});
```

The loading message will show till the window is completely loaded.

Comment: I don't want to show it when the page is loading. I want to show it when the script is running